# SMTP Relay to capture attachments

Tags: linux, email, open-source, smtp

Does anyone know of FOSS solutions (or general information) on setting up a Linux-bases SMTP mail relay that can do the following:

- Detect if a message has an attachment
- if so, save the attachment to a web-based storage solution
- remove the attachment from the message and insert a link to the file

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Python Milter package](http://www.bmsi.com/python/milter.html) comes bundled with a sample script which removes attachments deemed as dangerous and inserts a message - should be simlpe to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Ruby to do something similar.  In my case I was trying to process MMS/SMS.  There are some solutions out there for this.

Here's a good starting point, which is useful in general up to at least the point where they describe implementing a filter in postfix, which is probably the best method for actually handling mail programatically on linux without writing your own SMTP server.

http://railsmagazine.com/articles/3